# Trying to get property of non-object PHP not working

Tags: php

I have this code that access a api and gets the data and outputs it on my site, but I'm having a problem with the arrays and etc. I was wondering how can I access that data needed.

My problem is in:

```
foreach($entrieszz as $statSummaryzz)
{ $gamemodematchhistoryfellowPlayerslolsearch = $statSummaryzz->fellowPlayers->teamId; }
```

and its giving me error: Trying to get property of non-object

The data im trying to access:
[Trying to get games->fellowPlayers->teamId and also games->fellowPlayers->championId](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skhNE.png)

This is what I have:

```
<?php

$apiKey = 'e9044828-20e3-46cc-9eb5-545949299803';
$summonerName = 'tamini';
$new = rawurlencode($summonerName);

$news = str_replace(' ', '', $summonerName);
$str = strtolower($news);

// get the basic summoner info
$result = file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' . $new . '?api_key=' . $apiKey);
$summoner = json_decode($result)->$str;
$id = $summoner->id;

// var_dump($summoner);
?>  


<?php 


$clawzzeyu = file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/game/by-summoner/' . $id . '/recent?api_key=' . $apiKey);
$gazazzeyu = json_decode($clawzzeyu);

$entrieszz = $gazazzeyu->games;
usort($entrieszz, function($accc,$bccc){
    return $bccc->createDate-$accc->createDate;
});


foreach($entrieszz as $statSummaryzz){
    $gamemodematchhistoryfellowPlayerslolsearch = $statSummaryzz->fellowPlayers->teamId;
}

?>
```

Comment: What exactly is your PROBLEM? Describe it more clearly - In which row do you get the problem, and what error are you getting?

Comment: My problem is in this part  foreach($entrieszz as $statSummaryzz){
    $gamemodematchhistoryfellowPlayerslolsearch = $statSummaryzz->fellowPlayers->teamId;
    }                                                                                                                      and its giving me error: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Thanks, please add it to the body of the question and not as a comment - So your question will not get closed

Answer (score 0):

In your json sample there isn't teamId but only team
could be need

```
foreach($entrieszz as $statSummaryzz){
 $gamemodematchhistoryfellowPlayerslolsearch = $statSummaryzz->fellowPlayers->team;
}
```

Comment: That part i have working okay, the problem is                                                       $gamemodematchhistoryfellowPlayerslolsearch = $statSummaryzz->fellowPlayers->teamId;